# how to change background colour in echo

Tags: php, colors, background, echo

i am trying to apply the background color in echo using an inline style but it is not applying background color in however changes only the text color. i want to change background color in a particular part of the code

```
echo "<p style='color:orange';background-color:red;>"."record number: ".$rec_num. "</p>"."<br>"
```

program code is

```
    class db_access
    {
    private $_uname;
    private $_pass;
    private $_db;
    private $_server;

    //_construct connects databaseand fetchest he result
        public function __construct($server,$user_name,$password,$d_b)
        {
        $this->_server=$server;
        $this->_pass=$password;
        $this->_uname=$user_name;
        $this->_db=$d_b;
        $con=mysql_connect($this->_server,$this->_uname,$this->_pass);

        $db_found=mysql_select_db($this->_db,$con);
        if($db_found)
            {

            $sql="SELECT * FROM login";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
                if ($result)
                {
                    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
                    {
                    static $rec_num=1;
//inline css
                    echo "<p style='color:orange';background-color:red;>"."record number: ".$rec_num. "</p>"."<br>";
                    print $db_field['ID'] . "<BR>";
                    print $db_field['u_name'] . "<BR>";
                    print $db_field['pass'] . "<BR>";
                    print $db_field['email'] . "<BR><br><br>";
                    $rec_num++;
                    }
                    //returns the connection name that is used as a resource id in __destruct function
                    return $this->_con=$con;        
            }
                else {die(mysql_error());}

            }

        else 
        {return die(mysql_error());}
        } 


        // destruct function closes database    
        public function __destruct()
        {

        $close=mysql_close($this->_con);
        if($close)
        {print "connection closed";}
        else {die(mysql_error());}
        }   

    }
    $db=new db_access("127.0.0.1","root","","fabeeno");

    //var_dump($db);
```

Comment: echo "<p style='color:orange;background-color:red;'>"."record number: ".$rec_num. "</p>"."<br>";

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
echo "<p style='color:orange;background-color:red;'>record number: ".$rec_num. "</p><br>";
```

You have to end `'` single quote after the `background-color` style.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "<div style='background-color:red;'><p style='color:orange'>"."record number:     ".$rec_num. "</p></div>"."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can ajust only the print lines with styles

```
print "<p style='color: red;border: 1px solid black;height:20px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px;'>"."message!: ".$db_field['TEXTAREA1'] . "<br>";
```

after this i got an fancy box around the text =) i love boxes in many ways

so no echo where placed only `print {}` function

Many thanx and good luck

ps 
`['textarea1']` <-- is assigned to database so it reads only that table

Comment: Indeed call the easy style for the whole set ,Only for an bypass i needed to call an echo style for an Table , not an big deal but most easy to use , Meanwhile i figured it out how to implent extra icons in de print , as long i use "."<img scr style>"."

Comment: my example made print "<td style='color: red;
border: 0px solid black;
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;'>"."<img src='./icons/16x16/customer.png' id='Image2'      alt='' style='width: 16px;
height: 16px;
padding-right: 17px;
top: 2px;
position: relative;
'\";>"."</a>"."sometext: ".$db_field['TextArea1'] ."<td>";